# The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9' within the same start element tag

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-namespaces, xmlwriter

I'm getting this error

> The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9' within the same start element tag

while running this code

```
Dim writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(FileLocation + "StaticUrls3.xml")
Dim urlList As New List(Of String)

urlList.Add("link1")
urlList.Add("link2")
urlList.Add("link3")       

writer.WriteStartDocument()
writer.WriteStartElement("urlset")
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")

For Each aUrl As String In urlList
    writer.WriteStartElement("url")
    writer.WriteElementString("loc", aUrl)
    writer.WriteEndElement()
Next

writer.WriteEndElement()
writer.WriteEndDocument()
writer.Close()
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: In XML, QNames are tuples (local name, prefix, namespace URI). So you shouldn't output this element (urlset, '', '') and after that output a default namespace declaration. It's your element under no namespace or under some namespace?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
Const siteMapNamespace As String = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
Dim writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(FileLocation + "StaticUrls3.xml")
Dim urlList As New List(Of String)

urlList.Add("link1")
urlList.Add("link2")
urlList.Add("link3")       

writer.WriteStartDocument()
writer.WriteStartElement("urlset", siteMapNamespace)

For Each aUrl As String In urlList
    writer.WriteStartElement("url", siteMapNamespace)
    writer.WriteElementString("loc", aUrl)
    writer.WriteEndElement()
Next

writer.WriteEndElement()
writer.WriteEndDocument()
writer.Close()
```

Comment: So essentially, if you want to set the `xmlns` attribute of an element, do it via the second argument of `WriteStartElement` instead of `WriteAttributeString`.

Comment: Short answer yes.

But what is really going on is that you are specifying a namespace for all your elements.  And if you used a different namespace for different elements, I think you would get different xmlns declarations.

Comment: Same probleme for me. How can I define an "xmlns"-attribute and an "xmlns:r"-attribute for the same element?